# How to write a regular expression that recognises each expression individually?

Tags: regex, jsp

I'm trying to write a reg exp that matches the following code in a JSP:

```
="<%= "Index: " + index %>"
```

However if I write it in a general manner expressions on the same line that match this end up being combined:

```
value="<%= "items[" + Index + "].selected" %>" id="<%= "Checkbox" + Index %>"
```

Can someone help me figure out the reg exp to recognise the value and id tags separately so that I can put a search replace in to replace the outer double quotes with single quotes please?

Thanks,
Alexei Blue.

P.s.
So far I have this which isn 't specific enough:

```
"=<%=.*".*".*%>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the whole "<% %>" element including quotes, no matter what's inside the tag (apart from %) I would use this regex:

```
"<%=[^%]+%>"
```

You will probably need to escape the quotes in the code like this: `\"`

What it says is:

- Match "<%
- match everything that's not a %
- match %>"

**EDIT:**

If you are specifically interested only in the elements which have double quotes inside - use this:

```
"<%=([^%]*"){2}[^%]+%>"
```

- `([^%]*"){2}`: match everything that's not % (optional) and a double quote - repeat twice
- `[^%]+`: match any remaining characters

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`<%=\s*"(.+?)"(.+?)\s*%>`

the `?` after `+` makes `+` match as less as possible.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, +1 for explaining the +? operation.